# I want to create a PowerBI visualisation based on the info in the #Acumatica SO610500 Report

Tags: powerbi, acumatica

Is there a quick way to grab the schema for the report and convert it in to a generic inquiry rather than creating it again.

I need to ensure that the data returned matches the report exactly hence the desire to use the existing query that's the basis for the report.

Thanks all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is very low-quality because it is unclear what you are asking. Additionally, you should always include a sample of code that is causing the problem/not working. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

Richard, at least right now there is no way to convert report into a generic inquiry. You can create a GI to expose it to PowerBI and export results to Excel spreadsheet so it looks *almost* closer to a report…